# HttpClient body of map not called

Tags: angular

Does anyone know a reason why the body of the map function is not being called?

Other than the API not working, which I have checked and it is working.

```
this.httpClient.get(this.url)
  .map(
    (data) => {
      console.log('here');
      console.log(data);
      return data;
    }
  )
```

Comment: No we don't. We're not psychics. Make a [mcve] or post more of your code.

Comment: http call is made only if you subscribe. don't forget to subscribe!

Answer (score 2):

An `Observable` is cold, meaning that you have to subscribe on it to get it called and have a value.

```
this.httpClient.get(this.url)
  .map(
    (data) => {
      console.log('here');
      console.log(data);
      return data;
    }
  ).subscribe(data => console.log('GOT DATA', data));
```

Just add a subscription and the pipeline will be called.

Answer (score 0):

You need to mention the type of `data` i.e `Response` and apart from this `map` operator is used to parse your response in the desired format and it returns an observable which shall be `subscribed`

```
this.httpClient.get(this.url)
  .map(response => response.json())
  .subscribe(data=>console.log(data));
```

I suppose you are using angular >=4.2.3 which means you don't require `map` operatoer because The new `HttpClient` by default formats the response to JSON so we no longer need to parse it using `response.json():`

Comment: Hi  if this or any answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.