# How to avoid executing sort by date in an interval (Observable.interval(10000).subscribe) using typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

I used this function to sort data by datetime.

```
public sortbydate() {
    this.notification.sort((a, b) => {
      return this.getTime(new Date(a.datetime_device)) - this.getTime(new Date(b.datetime_device));
    }
    );
  }
```

In html I call this function like this code:

```
 <mat-checkbox class="example-margin" (click)="sortbydate()">Time</mat-checkbox>
```

My data notification call function `getAllNotifications();` in this interval, like in code

```
this.subscription = Observable.interval(10000).subscribe(x => {
    this.getAllNotifications();
});
  getAllNotifications() {
    this.ws.NotifGetAll().subscribe(
      notification => {
        this.notification = notification;
      }

    );
  }
```

What I ask is how to make sure that the order of dates is not broken in the case of this specified interval `interval(10000)`. For example, if the date of check-in should not break the order, if the date is not check-in, let's break the order.

I have tried to use this code, but without success:

```
isCheck: true;
    this.subscription = Observable.interval(10000).subscribe(x => {
      if (this.isCheck = true) {
        return this.getAllNotifications();
      } else {
        return false
      }

    });
```

Can you suggest any solution?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your sort method should return the sorted array, in order to make sure you'll receive the ordered version, aka if something alters your array after you called this function, you could receive a badly-ordered array.

```
public sortbydate(): any[] {
    return this.notification.sort((a, b) => {
      return this.getTime(new Date(a.datetime_device)) - this.getTime(new Date(b.datetime_device));
    });
  }
```

Then, by looking at [Observable.interval](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/interval.html) documentation, you can see that it emits a new integer value at each tick, so you can use that for your Observable pipeline:

```
const observable: Observable<any> = Observable.interval(1000).map(counter => {
     const notifications = this.sortbydate();
     // Make sure we don't go out of bounds
     if(counter >= notifications.length){
         counter = notifications.length ->
     }
     return notifications [counter];
});
```

Then you can simply subscribe to this observable, which will emit a new Notification at each tick, or the last one of the array. You can also handle the counter by yourself, adding a simple map operator to check what was the last emitted notification in order to make sure you'll emit all notifications if two are added at the same time. Because I'm not sure this is your use case, I didn't go too deep into this possibility.

Example:

```
const observable: Observable<any> = Observable.interval(1000).map(counter => {
     const notifications = this.sortbydate();
     // Make sure we don't go out of bounds
     if(counter >= notifications.length){
         counter = notifications.length ->
     }
     return notifications [counter];
});

observable.subscribe(notification => {
    // Using console.log as an example here but you can do whatever you want with it.
    console.log(notification);
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I try your code. But, when I write Observable.interval(1000).map --> my function dont call every 1000time, and when I write Observable.interval(1000).subscribe --> my function call every 1000 time and doesn't avoid my checkbox.

Comment: because observables are cold, so you have to subscribe to the produced observable, I'm adding an example in the answer. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49388085/httpclient-body-of-map-not-called/49388149#49388149

Comment: let observable: Observable<any> = Observable.interval(10000).map(x => {
      let notifications = this.sortbydate();
       if (x >= notifications.length) { //Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
        x = notifications.length
       }

      return notifications[x]

     });

Comment: Please,x >= notifications.length  Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Comment: @Aulonna You have to change this.sortbydate() method to return the result of the sort call, see the first code snippet of my answer

Comment: Yes, I forgot it. Please, when a new notification comes up, it does not display in html. In this moment   console.log(notification); is undefined. Please can you help please?

Comment: NotifGetAll() --> get me all events from ws, for this reason I do not get new notifications